# How to demonstrate the orthogonality of OFDM subcarriers?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm

Assume if we have $N$ OFDM subcarriers represented  by results of the inverse FFT of $N$ data symbols $\mathbf x$. As I know, the subcarriers of OFDM should be orthogonal. It means that

$$X(n)X(n+1) = 0\quad\text{where}\quad n = 0,\ldots,N-1$$

My question is that I can't get that right when doing it in MATLAB. For example suppose that $N=4$ and

$$\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}
0.7+0.7i\\ 
0.7-0.7i\\ 
-0.7+0.7i\\ 
0.7+0.7i\end{bmatrix}$$

is a data symbols gotten after QAM modulation.  The OFDM $N\times 1$ subcarriers are gotten by iFFT of the data symbol as below:

```
X = ifft(x)*sqrt(4);
```

It means that

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}
0.7+ 0.7i\\ 
1.4 + 0.0i\\
-0.7 + 0.7i\\
0.0 + 0.0i\end{bmatrix}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
X(1)\cdot X(2) &= (0.7000 + 0.7000i)\cdot(1.4000 + 0.0000i)\\
& = 0.9800 + 0.9800i
\end{align}$$

If subcarriers are orthogonal, that wil be zero.

Thus, my question, how can I demonstrate the otrhognality of OFDM subcarriers ?

Comment: Your definition of orthogonality is wrong: it would imply that at least one of $X(n)$ and $X(n+1)$ is zero.

Comment: How can we demonstrate the orthogonality in that case? Could you please help ?

Comment: Marcus already provided a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answer points out that the DFT is a matrix multiply. The matrix $\mathbf{D}$ is like this:

$$ \mathbf{D}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\
1 & \omega & \omega^2 & ... & \omega^{N-1} \\
1 & \omega^2 & \omega^4 & ... & \omega^{2(N-1)} \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
1 & \omega^{N-1} & \omega^{2(N-1)} & ... & \omega^{(N-1)(N-1)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $\omega=e^{j2\pi /N}$.

Take your example of four QPSK symbols that you want to modulate ($N=4$). So you do :

\begin{align}
\mathbf{s} &= \mathbf{D}\mathbf{x} \\
&= x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix} + x_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega\\\omega^2\\\omega^3 \end{bmatrix} + x_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega^2\\\omega^4\\\omega^6 \end{bmatrix} + x_4\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega^3\\\omega^6\\\omega^9 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

We now have the OFDM symbol $\mathbf{s}$ which took your original symbols $\mathbf{x}$ and mapped them across the $N$ subcarriers. The orthogonality is important because it means at the receiver we can do the FFT to get the symbols back. To demonstrate this, consider the receiver gets $\mathbf{s}$ and wants to generate its first symbol estimate $\hat{x}_1$:

\begin{align}
\hat{x}_1 &= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{s} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix} \bigg( x_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix} + x_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega\\\omega^2\\\omega^3 \end{bmatrix} + x_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega^2\\\omega^4\\\omega^6 \end{bmatrix} + x_4\begin{bmatrix}1\\\omega^3\\\omega^6\\\omega^9 \end{bmatrix} \bigg) \\
&= 4x_1 + 0 + 0 + 0
\end{align}

The fact that you got three zeros there is the orthogonal part, leaving it to you to do the inner product to convince yourself of that (inner product between $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ is $\mathbf{x}^H\mathbf{y}$). And this comes from the fact that $\mathbf{D}$ is unitary, $\mathbf{D}^H\mathbf{D}=\mathbf{D}\mathbf{D}^H=\mathbf{I}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear explanation. In your case, $s$ is similar to $X$ in my question. but how can I demonstrate that each element in $s$  is orthogonal on the other.  it means that $s(1)s(2)=0$

Comment: What you're saying about orthogonal isn't right. $s_1s_2 \neq 0$ in general, do you have a reference for where you got that?

Comment: @Fatima_Ali see above

Comment: Yes,  $s_1s_2$ doesn't equal to zeros as I demonstrated by MATLAB above in my question

Comment: @Fatima_Ali what I mean is that is not a problem. Where did you get that their product equals zero?

Answer (score 1):

Orthogonality is defined as "the inner product of two vectors equals zero".

Now, in OFDM, the transmit vector for a single subcarrier is exactly one row vector $\mathbf D_k$ of the DFT Matrix $\mathbf D$, multiplied by the complex value of a symbol $c_k$, i.e. $c_K \mathbf D_K$.

Two different subcarriers $k, l, k\ne l$ hence have the inner product $\langle c_k\mathbf D_k,c_l\mathbf D_l\rangle$; inner products are linear things, hence that's

\begin{align}
\langle c_k\mathbf D_k,c_l\mathbf D_l\rangle &= c_kc_l \langle \mathbf D_k,\mathbf D_l\rangle\\
&= c_kc_l \begin{cases}0&k\ne l\\\|\mathbf D_k\| & k = l\end{cases} &\text{q.e.d.},
\end{align}

because the DFT matrix is unitary.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as I see $X(n)$ explained in my question is the same of $c_KD_K$ mentioned in your reply, Is that right? Could you please implement that on the example I gave in my question? ..

Comment: yes, it is. Since I think you're very much able to  substitute one variable for another, I don't see the point in modifying my proof – it's a general demonstration (a proof!) of the orthogonality, and you just inserting your vectors will work, albeit being super boring (which is why I have no interest in doing it, especially since it'd feel like I'm doing even the last bit of your work).

Comment: I mean in your last equation, if $c_k$ is the complex value of a symbol which is for example $0.7+0.7i$  and $c_l$ is another value of a symbol which is  $0.7+0.7i$  .. their inner multiplication is not 0 ! it means $c_k$ $c_l$ is not 0 in all cases

Comment: I mean if $X(n)$ is $c_KD_K$ it means that $X(n)X(n+1)$ won't be zeros as I explained in my question.

Comment: you need to read the full line. There's a multiplication between $c_lc_k$ and the case $0$ or the case $\|\mathbf D_k\|$. This is standard notation for cases.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand your answer, could you please explain more regarding how the inner product of time-domain subcarriers can equal to $0$ ?

Comment: @Fatima_Ali you'll need to be more precise in your question please. What of the formulas I wrote do you *not* understand? I'm a bit confused, because this is literally just using the very definition of  "orthogonal".

Answer (score 1):

I would prove it like that (in Matlab)

```
F=dftmtx(4);
dot(F(:,1),F(:,2))
ans =
     0
```

Comment: Yes, but how to prove that after multiplying with the symbols ?